# error A1000 with MASM visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, visual-studio-2015, masm

I'm reading a book "Guide to Assembly Language" by James T.Streib in order to learn Assembly but I can't compile the test example on visual studio 2015 because of the following error:

```
1>   Assembling: 
1>MASM : fatal error A1000: cannot open file
1>  Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 12.00.31101.0
```

I added this in the Custom Build Tool Command Line of my main.asm file:

```
ml -c -Zi "-Fl$(IntDir)\$(InputName).lst" "-Fo$(IntDir)\$(InputName).obj" "$(InputPath)"
```

And Outputs:

```
$(IntDir)\$(InputName).obj
```

I also added msvcrt.lib in the Additional Dependencies of the linker.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following for the Command Line field:

```
ml -c -Zi "-Fl$(IntDir)%(Filename).lst" "-Fo$(IntDir)%(Filename).obj" "%(FullPath)"
```

and this for the Output field:

```
$(IntDir)%(Filename).obj
```

The old "Input" [macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx) are deprecated in Visual Studio 2015 and have been replaced by new "item metadata macros" that use the `%()` syntax.

Here's a screenshot showing where I've entered these lines. Note that I've changed to the "Configuration" and "Platform" pulldowns to "All Configurations" and "All Platforms" respectively so that these parameters are used no matter what sort of build is being performed.

[image: Visual Studio 2015 .ASM Custom Build Tool Property Page]

Comment: Hum, I still have my error + a new one Error 2 error MSB3073: The command "ml -c -Zi "-FlDebug\\.lst" "-FoDebug\\.obj" ""
:VCEnd" exited with code 1.

Comment: You don't seem to be using the line I gave. Try cutting and pasting the Command Line field **exactly** as it appears in my answer.

Comment: I copied it exactly :(

Comment: Perhaps you've copied it into the wrong place then.

Comment: It's in the properties panel of the main.asm file under custom build tool, General. In the Configuration Properties tab I've changed the Item Type to Curstom Build Tool, is it the right place ?

Comment: I've added a screenshot to show where I added these lines.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the same but still with errors :( http://puu.sh/jBSax.png

Comment: Okay, I've rebuilt a project and it works fine :( Thanks a lot for the help Ross !